# AJAX request calls the error callback method

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

> jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/jsontest/',
            data: {
                "username": "admin",
                "password": "admin"
            },
            async: false,
            success: function (data, status) {
                alert(data + "\nstatus:" + status)
            },
            fail: function () {
                alert("fail");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error" + data);
            },
            dataType: 'text'
        });
    });
})
```

> views.py

```
def post_test(request):
   print "get request!"
   return HttpResponse('hello')
```

> urls,py

```
url('^jsontest/$', post_test),
```

And the django console returns

> get request!
>
> "POST /jsontest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5

why it just not calls the success callback method?
Any advice?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `success` takes only 1 parameter

Comment: is the `submit_button` part of a form submit?

Comment: Can you show us you template where the button is located?

Comment: umm, if you are on Django 1.7+, you can return in the view json response like this: return JsonResponse({status:'hello'}) and in the ajax success method you can access it by doing data.status